# Xquery retriving information (separate duplicate fields into individual values)

Tags: xml, xslt, xquery

XML file result from ***food:food-item($food:fps-photo-atlas)***

```
<portion>
<food-description unit="g">Spaghetti     </food-description>
<food-number file-type="jpg">3    </food-number>
<portion-size>
<size tag="1">55    </size>
<size tag="2">108    </size>
<size tag="3">161    </size>
<size tag="4">214    </size>
<size tag="5">266    </size>
<size tag="6">319    </size>
<size tag="7">372    </size>
<size tag="8">425    </size>
</portion-size>
<size-increment eight-plus="478">52.86    </size-increment>
</portion>
```

My XQUERY (XML to HTML section)

```
for $x in food:food-item($food:fps-photo-atlas)/portion/portion-size
return
<i>{data($x/size)}</i>
}
```

Current Results from my current XQuery

```
<i>55 108 161 214 266 319 372 425</i>
```

Preferred result..

```
<i>55</i>
<i>108</i>
<i>161</i>
<i>214</i>
<i>266</i>
<i>319</i>
<i>372</i>
<i>425</i>
```

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for $x in food:food-item($food:fps-photo-atlas)/portion/portion-size/size
return
<i>{data($x)}</i>
}
```

Comment: @Killrawr: This is a correct and good answer that *fixes* your code and isn't "copy pasting". Please, read well and restrain from rude comments that only show lack of understanding and lack of respect to the people who are experts and have spent their valuable time in showing to you a solution that corrects your own. +1 for Mads Hansen.

Comment: my sincere apologizes Mads.. after looking at the code I could actually notice the difference. Thanks Dimitire for bringing that to my attention.

Comment: Mads: You may be confused by these comments, because the OP deleted his initial comment that was saying you just copied and pasted his code...

Comment: Yeah I'm new to xquery so at the moment a lot of it looks the same till you look at the nitty gritty.. thanks Mads (Sorry for being a douche with my initial comment)

Comment: No worries. Although the code may be correct, my answer could have been better and included an explanation or at least a description of the change to explain why your code wasn't working and what needed to be done differently.